# Gradle Multiproject and Kotlin Multiplatform - KMM Framework with API dependency on sibling project

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle-multi-project-build

### Context

I'm working on a project where the web service and mobile clients share as much Kotlin code as possible. The `"api"` and `"client"` subprojects have a dependency on the `"models"` subproject.

The API subproject is the web service. As far as I understand it, it consumes the JVM output from the Model subproject.

The Client subproject is for consumption by the iOS, macOS, and Android apps. Again, according to my kindergarten-level understanding, the mobile apps consume Kotlin/Native  and Kotlin/JVM output.

```
include("models", "api", "client")
```

**Abbreviated `gradle.build.kts` for `"client"`**

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.kmp)
    ...
}

kotlin {

    android()

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "AwesomeFramework"
        }
    }

    listOf(
        macosArm64(),
        macosX64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "AwesomeFramework"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {

        all {
            languageSettings.optIn("kotlin.experimental.ExperimentalObjCName")
            languageSettings.optIn("kotlin.experimental.ExperimentalObjCRefinement")
        }

        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api(project(":models"))
                ....
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies { ... }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }

        val macosX64Main by getting
        val macosArm64Main by getting
        val macMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            macosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            macosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    ...
}
```

**Abbreviated `gradle.build.kts` for `"models"`**

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.kmp)
    ...
}

kotlin {

    jvm()

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "AwesomeModels"
        }
    }

    listOf(
        macosArm64(),
        macosX64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "AwesomeModels"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies { ... }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies { ... }
        }

        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }

        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }

        val macosX64Main by getting
        val macosArm64Main by getting
        val macMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            macosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            macosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}
```

I thought setting my project up this way would allow for the Models subproject to remain fairly stable and not require rebuilds. *Open to suggestions if I've made things harder on myself with this configuration.*

### The Problem

I do not understand how `dependencies { api(project(":models")) }` works for KMM.

In the Models project, I have iOS specific code in the `iosMain` source set. When I build the iOS app (in Xcode), I see the Client types and the Model types that Client uses. These types are preceded with `Models` (e.g., `ModelsUser`).

However, I don't see methods, functions, and types the Client project doesn't use. Furthermore, the iOS specific code in the Model subproject isn't available. I think this kinda makes sense - setting the dependency to `api(...)` is probably going to export the smallest number of symbols possible.

So, maybe I should *also* consume the Model project inside of my iOS app? In other words...

```
import AwesomeFramework
import AwesomeModels
```

However, the problem is there's nothing to provide a linkage between the two frameworks. The `ModelsUser` class emitted from Client is separate and distinct from the `User` class emitted from the Models subproject. ‍♂️

I could smash the Models and Client projects together, but I would like to understand why that's the most "correct" solution.

I've reached the end of my (very limited) Gradle and Kotlin Multiplatform knowledge. **Looking for solutions or resources that would help fill in the gaps.**

Comment: generally you don't want to have multiple KMM shared modules for iOS - they can't know of each other so all types used in both modules will be re-implemented in each module and so gonna be independent, e.g.  `AwesomeFramework.User` and `AwesomeModels.User` are different classes. It's suggested to use a single shared module. You still can have multi module setup, but there should be single module that combines all modules you need to share with iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the project setup is correct.
In order to fully export the `models` to ObjC/Swift you'll need to export the dependency:

```kotlin
it.binaries.framework {
    baseName = "AwesomeFramework"
    export(project(":models"))
}
```

Source: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-build-native-binaries.html#export-dependencies-to-binaries

At the moment frameworks generated by Kotlin are indeed considered to contain unique declarations. Which is why your `User` model from `AwesomeFramework` isn't the same as the one from `AwesomeModels`.
Please follow [KT-42250](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42250/Support-compiling-Kotlin-module-to-Swift-Obj-C-module-that-doesnt-contain-all-dependencies) for updates.